# Querying through rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm having trouble getting my models associated, or I'm somehow ignorant about how to query through the associations.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
end
```

Now, if I go into my rails console and ask for `Entry.first`, I get:

```
Entry Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" LIMIT 1
=> #<Entry id: 1, category_id: 1, duration: 2.0, image: "3", note: "4", url: "5", created_at: "2012-03-03 02:22:23", updated_at: "2012-03-03 02:22:23">
```

and if I ask `Category.first` for I get:

```
Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" LIMIT 1 
=> #<Category id: 1, name: "Dev", created_at: "2012-03-03 02:17:17", updated_at: "2012-03-03 02:17:17">
```

But if I ask for `Entry.first.category.name`, it breaks and I get:

```
Entry Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `category' for #<Entry:0x007fec4d217848>
from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:126:in `method_missing'
from (irb):63
from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Why is this? How can I get the name for the category through the entry? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case a categories table should have `entry_id` column, but you have `category_id` in entries one.

So try changing:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :entry
end
```

Or change your db schema.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it both directions but wasn't aware that I needed to reload the rails console after making model changes. Now I know! :)